Issues using Flask on Python local network
I want to access the url on other device in the same network but sometimes on my another PC or cellphone appears Timed_Out or Unrecheable:
This is my code:
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, jsonify
import socket

app = Flask(__name__)

FILE_DIRECTORY = '/home/josemoraila/Documentos'
FILE_NAME = 'saludos.txt'

def get_ip_address():
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    return ip_address

@app.route('/api/latest-version', methods=['GET'])
def latest_version():
    ip_address = get_ip_address()
    response = {
        'version': '1.1.4',
        'download_url': f'http://{ip_address}:5000/download/{FILE_NAME}'
    }
    return jsonify(response)

@app.route('/download/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(FILE_DIRECTORY, filename, as_attachment=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)

And on the terminal appears:
 * Serving Flask app 'flaskPrueba'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://192.168.1.14:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 213-885-431

but on my another pc when I try to enter in: http://192.168.1.14:5000/download/saludos.txt there's an error.

What is the error?

Add cors as a middleware. and try

It didn't work, I checked if my firewall allows the port I'm using and even so I'm struggling
